# arrange images and text left and right simultaneously

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load images and quotes left and right vertically but I am having issue with the 3rd image and quotes. From somewhere margin css is getting added but I am not able to find the problem. I have given working model to undersand my problem pls check!

[working website](https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/)

```css
.float-left {
  float: right;
}

.next {
  margin: auto 25px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate__animated animate__backInRight animate__delay-1s flex" loading="lazy">
  <img src="./v-kart-restaurant-billing-software2.png" width="700" height="200" loading="lazy" />
  <div class="margin-10">
    <p>Simple dashboard for easy use of the pos software</p>
    <p>
      v-kart uses a simple and easy-to-use dashboard so that anyone will be able to use our software easily it has bigger buttons for easy and prolonged use of software
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft animate__delay-1s float-left flex" loading="lazy">
  <div class="margin-10">
    <p>inventory for easy use of the billing software</p>
    <p>
      v-kart uses a simple and easy-to-use inventory which let you add new food items easily and edit the price details
    </p>
  </div>
  <img src="./v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-inventory-main.png" width="700" loading="lazy" />
</div>

<div class="animate__animated animate__backInRight animate__delay-1s flex" loading="lazy">
  <img src="./v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-add-type-of-food.png" width="700" height="200" loading="lazy" />
  <div class="margin-10">
    <p>Easy to add a new type food type to our pos software</p>
    <p>
      our billing software is different from other pos systems because the software is dynamic and whenever a new type of dish has to be added to the software we can easily group them by adding a new type
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: and the `CSS`, please.

Comment: @ths i hav added css

Comment: Rather bad idea to mess around with float inside a flexbox layout. Also rather bad, to have the order of the content in your HTML vary, based simply on how you want it to _look_. This should be done using the same structure for all those elements, and then applying the `order` property to change their _visual_ order. And if you want this to be applied in an odd-even-odd etc. manner - then you can directly use the CSS selectors that exist for exactly such a purpose, instead of coding this info your HTML in the first place.

Comment: Be aware you named the CSS class `float-left`. But it has `float: right;` styling - that only causes confusion even if you have the correct idea. Please make this a snippet with the `<>` button. Use [Lorem Picsum](https://picsum.photos/) for images.

Comment: @menucd If I can understand what you want, I'm sure I can help. Do you want two pictures on left with their text to the right then under that the other two pictures right with their text on left? or what?

Comment: is this the kind of layout you are looking for? [responsive layout](https://codepen.io/Mad7Dragon/pen/zYjbWNY)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise to work with `display:flex` and `flex-flow` here.

*This would also allow to keep the same HTML structure for all sections, which might be useful for the responsive.*

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex--left {
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

.content,
.image {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="animate__animated animate__backInRight animate__delay-1s flex" loading="lazy">
  <img src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software2.png" width="700" height="200" loading="lazy" class="image" />
  <div class="margin-10 content">
    <p>Simple dashboard for easy use of the pos software</p>
    <p>
      v-kart uses a simple and easy-to-use dashboard so that anyone will be able to use our software easily it has bigger buttons for easy and prolonged use of software
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft animate__delay-1s flex flex--left" loading="lazy">
  <img src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-inventory-main.png" width="700" loading="lazy" class="image" />
  <div class="margin-10 content">
    <p>inventory for easy use of the billing software</p>
    <p>
      v-kart uses a simple and easy-to-use inventory which let you add new food items easily and edit the price details
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="animate__animated animate__backInRight animate__delay-1s flex" loading="lazy">
  <img src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-add-type-of-food.png" width="700" height="200" loading="lazy" class="image" />
  <div class="margin-10 content">
    <p>Easy to add a new type food type to our pos software</p>
    <p>
      our billing software is different from other pos systems because the software is dynamic and whenever a new type of dish has to be added to the software we can easily group them by adding a new type
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="animate__animated animate__backInRight animate__delay-1s flex flex--left" loading="lazy">
  <img src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-loginpage.png" width="700" height="200" loading="lazy" class="image" />
  <div class="margin-10 content">
    <p>v-kart has high security features</p>
    <p>
      restaurant billing includes multiple billing users so we created the best security features for your software so the owner gets daily profit and loss correctly
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `body > div:nth-child(3){float: left}`, or:

```
.animate__animated.animate__backInRight.animate__delay-1s.flex {
    float: left;
}
```

and it will arrange the third div properly.

Here's the working model:

```css
/*style.css*/

.float-left {
  float: right;
}

.next {
  margin: auto 25px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}


/*new code from here*/

.animate__animated.animate__backInRight.animate__delay-1s.flex {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="animate__animated animate__backInRight animate__delay-1s flex" loading="lazy">
    <img src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software2.png" width="700" height="200" loading="lazy">
    <div class="margin-10">
      <p>Simple dashboard for easy use of the pos software</p>
      <p>
        v-kart uses a simple and easy-to-use dashboard so that anyone will be able to use our software easily it has bigger buttons for easy and prolonged use of software
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft animate__delay-1s float-left flex" loading="lazy">
    <div class="margin-10">
      <p>inventory for easy use of the billing software</p>
      <p>
        v-kart uses a simple and easy-to-use inventoy which let you add new food items easily and edit the price details
      </p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-inventory-main.png" width="700" loading="lazy">
  </div>

  <div class="animate__animated animate__backInRight animate__delay-1s flex" loading="lazy">
    <img src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-add-type-of-food.png" width="700" height="200" loading="lazy">
    <div class="margin-10">
      <p>Easy to add a new type food type to our pos software</p>
      <p>
        our billing software is different from other pos systems because the software is dynamic and whenever a new type of dish has to be added to the software we can easily group them by adding a new type
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft animate__delay-1s float-left flex" loading="lazy">
    <div class="margin-10">
      <p>v-kart has high security features</p>
      <p>
        restaurant billing includes multiple billing users so we created the best security features for your software so the owner gets daily profit and loss correctly
      </p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-loginpage.png" width="700" loading="lazy">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I replaced `./` with `https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/`, but you can change that for your site's need.

Comment: can u make a working model

Comment: sure, I just added a code snippet. You can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that you have is in your `float` settings. I would not set floating if I am using a `flex` display.

So, I would recommend removing the floating and use the power of `flex`. I have modified your `css` and html a little bit to support aligning of the `html` items / contents. I have separated the image and quote 50,50 percent for the container to make it look good. Feel free to play around it.

Also, you do not need to set a certain width for image in the given scenario, this way your image might go over its parent causing it to either trigger the scrolls or would overlap the text.

```css
.next {
  margin: auto 25px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.display-flex {
   display: flex;
}
.w-half {
   width: 50%;
}
.m-10px {
   margin: 10px;
}
.align-center{
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate__animated animate__backInRight animate__delay-1s display-flex align-center" loading="lazy">
  <img class="w-half" src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software2.png" loading="lazy" />
  <div class="w-half m-10px">
<p>Simple dashboard for easy use of the pos software</p>
<p>
  v-kart uses a simple and easy-to-use dashboard so that anyone will be able to use our software easily it has bigger buttons for easy and prolonged use of software
</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft animate__delay-1s float-left display-flex align-center" loading="lazy">
  <div class="w-half m-10px">
<p>inventory for easy use of the billing software</p>
<p>
  v-kart uses a simple and easy-to-use inventory which let you add new food items easily and edit the price details
</p>
  </div>
  <img class="w-half" src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-inventory-main.png" loading="lazy" />
</div>

<div class="animate__animated animate__backInRight animate__delay-1s display-flex align-center" loading="lazy">
  <img class="w-half" src="https://serene-cascaron-252692.netlify.app/v-kart-restaurant-billing-software-add-type-of-food.png" loading="lazy" />
  <div class="w-half m-10px">
<p>Easy to add a new type food type to our pos software</p>
<p>
  our billing software is different from other pos systems because the software is dynamic and whenever a new type of dish has to be added to the software we can easily group them by adding a new type
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use float with flex. Flex was invented so float wouldn't need to be used anymore because it wasn't great. Flex has hierarchy so float will be ignored.

If you want the second div to appear before the first you can use a flex order rule.